# how to pass the select option value into "href" in play framework 2.0.4 java

Tags: playframework-2.0

view:

```
              <select  name="id" id="drop">
                             @for(pag <- page){

                             @if(pag.tenant_location_id == loc.id){

                             <option value="@pag.id">@pag.pagename</option>
                             }

                             }
                            </select>


          <a href="@routes.Project.edit(drop down selected value)>Edit</a>
```

I tried with javascript var x= document.getElementById('drop') its not accepting javascript variable value.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass JavaScript value (which is declared on the client side) as the Scala param (which is compiled at runtime), all params you want to pass to Scala function must be declared in the view and get some value ie. from controller or object .

Solution: build whole url in option's value, so using basic JavaScript you can just replace the `href` on the `onchange` event. Sample (not tested, but should work with jQuery)

```
<select  name="id" id="drop">
    <option value="">Choose the service...</option>
    @for(pag <- page){
        @if(pag.tenant_location_id == loc.id){
            <option value="@routes.Project.edit(pag.id)">@pag.pagename</option>
        }
    }
</select>

<a href="#" id="editBtn">Edit</a>
<script>
    $(document).on('change', '#drop', function(){
        $('#editBtn').attr('href', $(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,i have tried but script is not working, its always go for #. will you suggest me working script as like you mentioned in your post.

Comment: As I wrote - I wrote it from top of my head as a reference, Check fixed sample, it works now - replace `this.val()` with `$(this).val()`. Of course I assume that you included jQuery lib